# In a bash script: using cat on a file with the contents ".*" yields unexpected results

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My problem can be reproduced with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ".*" > foo.txt
echo $(cat foo.txt)
```

When I run this script I get a list of folders/files in my current directory:

```
$ ./test.sh 
. .. .testfile
$ cat foo.txt 
.*
```

My question is really a two parter:

1) Why does this happen?

2) Is there any way to get the literal string ".*" rather than a file list returned from $(cat [args])?

I originally ran into this problem working on a more complex script. Fixing this with an additional option passed into cat and/or alternative syntax would be ideal.

Comment: Incidentally, http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught this bug, without you needing to bother humans about it here.

Comment: ...it's also #14 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the result returned by `$()` is un-quoted. It is equivalent to:

```
echo .*
```

which is subject to shell expansion.

You should double quote it:

```
echo "$(cat foo.txt)"
```

It will give correct output `.*`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $(cat foo.txt)
```

Capturing cat's output and then echoing it right back out is not only redundant, it's error prone, as you've discovered. Just write:

```
cat foo.txt
```

Simpler, faster, it's the bees knees!

Or if you *really, really* want to capture it and then print it back out, use quotes. Quotes will prevent the `.*` from being interpreted as wildcards.

```
echo "$(cat foo.txt)"
```

There are still subtle problems with this command. If `foo.txt` contains `-n`, for instance, `echo` won't print `-n`, it'll print nothing. It turns out that `echo` simply isn't usable if you're the extra paranoid type. The super safe option is to eschew `echo` in favor of `printf`.

```
printf '%s\n' "$(cat foo.txt)"
```

This is as safe as one can get. It prints the contents of `foo.txt` and won't get tripped up by any special characters.

Although, you know, this is an awfully long winded way of writing:

```
cat foo.txt
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "$(<foo.txt)"` might be a bit more time-efficient for small files, avoiding the need to invoke an external executable for `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

Use More Quotes !

```
echo ".*" > foo.txt
echo "$(cat foo.txt)"
.*
```

The double quotes are mandatory, to **avoid shell expansion**:

Without the double quotes, all the characters are expanded from the shell, so the `*` becomes files in current directory